# Cannot psql-connect azure postgres server if created with admin-password in keyvault

Tags: postgresql, azure-devops, psql, azure-keyvault

I've been trying to create azure postgres server using admin-password from key vault. Using secret obtained with command `az keyvault secret show` I always fail in connection the server from my pc. When using the same text string that was stored as the key vault secret in the create-command I don't have any problems when connecting from my PC.

```
jaana@Azure:~$ az postgres server create --location westeurope --resource-group my-rg  --name fortunate-postgres-server  --admin-user adminU  --admin-password changeMe+1 --sku-name B_Gen5_1
jaana@Azure:~$ secret=$(az keyvault secret show --name "AdminPassWord" --vault-name unfortunate-kv --query "value"
jaana@Azure:~$ echo $secret
"changeMe+1"
jaana@Azure:~$ az postgres server create --location westeurope --resource-group my-rg  --name unfortunate-postgres-server  --admin-user adminU  --admin-password $secret --sku-name B_Gen5_1
```

in my pc:

```
$ psql "host=fortunate-postgres-server.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=postgres user=adminU@fortunate-postgres-server password=changeMe+1 sslmode=require"
psql (9.2.2, server 9.6.21)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 9.6.
         Some psql features might not work.
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \q

$ psql "host=unfortunate-postgres-server.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=postgres user=adminU@unfortunate-postgres-server password=changeMe+1 sslmode=require"
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "adminU"
```

How can this be possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the explanation to @Jaana's answer.

In this case, there is a double quotes issue, if you use `az keyvault secret show` without `-o tsv` parameter, it will output the value with the double quotes, then when you reference the variable in `az postgres server create`, it will pass the value with double quotes.

To solve the issue, `-o tsv` is the solution, the output is guaranteed to be unquoted.

See details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli#tsv-output-format

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `-o tsv` into command `az keyvault secret show` solved the problem